# New MCC Account for adwords

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

We are currently having one active MCC account for production. We want to create a new MCC account for our testing purpose. If we apply for the approval of new account it gets rejected from Google it says there already exists one account.

How to create two MCC Account so that we can separate out the production and non production activity completely from each other?

We want both the accounts to be live and the ads get live and some impression,clicks can be accumulated against the ads.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Special Test accounts can be create for testing, but they can't serve ads or accrue impressions/clicks.

I'd recommend creating a test account (not just a second live account, a special test account) for all testing. But you'll have to test all reporting related functionality on a live production Google Ads account.